# How you send email with php where the sender has two emails?

Tags: php, email

There is a standard that says that you can send from multiple email addresses. I mean the sender header can have multiple email addresses.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.2

I have tried different combinations of the `mail` functions but neither one worked.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com, dat@teddy.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>


<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" . 'From: dat@teddy.com' . "\r\n"
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: More information please. What did you try, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Because there is a standard that allows me to do so.

Comment: No, one email where the sender header has two emails.

Comment: [From RFC5322:](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.6.2) _"From" and a **comma-
   separated list** of one or more mailbox specifications.  If the fromfield contains more than one mailbox specification in the mailbox-list, then the sender field, containing the field name "Sender" and a single mailbox specification, MUST appear in the message.  In either case, an optional reply-to field MAY also be included, which contains the field name "Reply-To" and a comma-separated list of one or more
   addresses._

Comment: So based on the RFC snippet above, you need to include a `Sender: webmaster@example.com` header specifying the _one single_ address actually sending the message.  I've never, to my recollection, encountered one of these in the wild, and would not be surprised if client and MTA support is spotty.

Comment: @george http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_transport_agent

Comment: @george I'm sorry this question got such a negative response - it wasn't deserved.  People ought to read RFC's.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It got the negative response when the entirety of the question was "I have tried different combinations mail functions but neither one worked." After the edits it became a good one. Voting to reopen, hopefully others will as well.

Comment: @jprofitt I voted to reopen as well.  Downvotes kept coming, even after the RFC was linked in. Like broken windows in a factory...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out, hope it will work

```
$headers =  "From: Website  <webmaster@example.com,dat@teddy.com> \r\n";
```

or this

```
$headers =  "From: WebMaster <webmaster@example.com>, Dat<dat@teddy.com> \r\n";
```

Comment: The first parameter is receiver. I'm looking for the "sender".

Comment: I have send one email to metu.edu.tr and one to gmail.com. Gmail says that the sender is only the Webmaster, not Dat. And both of Webmaster and Dat are at reply header though I didn't put and reply headers. The email that I have send to METU has worked as expected.